# Maven 3.9.5 - Error: -classpath requires class path specification

Tags: java, maven, java-21, maven-3.9.5

When running `mvn -v` or `mvn -version` I receive the following error:
`Error: -classpath requires class path specification`

However, I have followed the instruction as defined on both:
https://www.oracle.com/uk/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk21-windows and https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

What is missing or misconfigured that could be causing this error?

**I am using:**
Maven 3.9.5
Java Version: 21

**Directory Locations:**
Maven is located at:
`C:\Maven`
Java JDK is located at:
`C:\Program Files\Java`

**Environment Variables:**
User Variables:
`JAVA_HOME`: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21`
`M2_HOME`: `C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.9.5-src\apache-maven-3.9.5\apache-maven\src`
`M2`: `%M2_HOME%\bin`
`MAVEN_HOME`: `C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.9.5-src\apache-maven-3.9.5\apache-maven\src`

**Path Variable:** // This reflects my various attempts to get this to work.
`%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin`
`C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.9.5-src\apache-maven-3.9.5\`
`%M2%`
`C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.9.5-src\apache-maven-3.9.5\apache-maven\src\bin`
`%M2_HOME%`
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21`

Lastly, when running `java -version`, the following is returned:

```
java version "21" 2023-09-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 21+35-LTS-2513)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21+35-LTS-2513, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Have you downloaded the src or the bin archives (zip file for windows ` apache-maven-3.9.5-bin.zip`) artifact? Why do you use M2_HOME?

Comment: @khmarbaise I was using the src archives, I've since changed to the bin archives and it all works. Thank you very much for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying with source. Download the binaries from https://dlcdn.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.9.5/binaries/apache-maven-3.9.5-bin.zip

Comment: Fantastic, this worked! This was absolutely the problem, I see now that he source files are for building maven yourself. Thanks very much for your answer!